# awk to add closing parenthesis if field begins with opening parenthesis

Tags: awk

I have an `awk` that seemed straight-forward, but I seem to be having a problem. In the file below if `$5` starts with a `(` then to that string a `)` is added at the end.  However `if`$5`does not start with a`(`then nothing is done. The out is separated by a tab.  The`awk`is almost right but I am not sure how to add the condition to only add a`)`if the field starts with a`(`.  Thank you :).

**file**

```
chr7 100490775 100491863 chr7:100490775-100491863 ACHE
chr7 100488568 100488719 chr7:100488568-100488719 ACHE;DJ051769
chr1 159174749 159174770 chr1:159174749-159174770 (ACKR1
chr1 159175223 159176240 chr1:159175223-159176240 (ACKR1
```

**awk tried**

```
awk -v OFS='\t' '{print $1,$2,$3,$4,""$5")"}' file
```

**current output**

```
chr7    100490775   100491863   chr7:100490775-100491863    ACHE)
chr7    100488568   100488719   chr7:100488568-100488719    ACHE;DJ051769)
chr1    159174749   159174770   chr1:159174749-159174770    (ACKR1)
chr1    159175223   159176240   chr1:159175223-159176240    (ACKR1)
```

**desired output** (line 1 and 2 nothing is done but line 3 and 4 have a `)` added to the end)

```
chr7    100490775   100491863   chr7:100490775-100491863    ACHE
chr7    100488568   100488719   chr7:100488568-100488719    ACHE;DJ051769
chr1    159174749   159174770   chr1:159174749-159174770    (ACKR1)
chr1    159175223   159176240   chr1:159175223-159176240    (ACKR1)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$ awk -v OFS='\t' '{p = substr($5,1,1)=="(" ? ")" : ""; $5=$5 p}1' mp.txt
chr7    100490775   100491863   chr7:100490775-100491863    ACHE
chr7    100488568   100488719   chr7:100488568-100488719    ACHE;DJ051769
chr1    159174749   159174770   chr1:159174749-159174770    (ACKR1)
chr1    159175223   159176240   chr1:159175223-159176240    (ACKR1)
```

Check the first character of the 5th field. If it is `(` append a `)` to the end, otherwise append the empty string.

By appending something (where one of the somethings is "nothing" :) in all cases, we force awk to reconstitute the record with the defined (tab) output separator, which saves us from having to print the individual fields. The trailing `1` acts as an always-true pattern whose default action is simply to print the reconstituted line.

Comment: Thank you very much for your help and explanations :).